# Bootstrap carousel content fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a site mcelroymotors.com. If you look at the carousel on the homepage a caption pops up on the first slide with text. I wish to have this occur on all slides however it seems that it does not appear after the first one.

Comment: It is better to provide code snippet or jsfiddle for such questions

Comment: Just thought it better to show the website as i'm finding it difficult to include all the necessary code in a snippet. Let me know if this is okay.

Comment: Realised its to do with use of slid and slide. Should have used slid.bs.carousel and slide.bs.carousel. Thanks for the input anyway and if anyone wants to give me tips regarding posting they're welcome to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
#myCarousel .carousel-caption > div {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Set opacity to 1 and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My intention is for each slide to come in with the title but then for the text to fade in after a short period. Your answer means the text is there permanently. First time posting so apologies if my coding etiquette isnt great.

Comment: Listen for the 'slide.bs.carousel' event, and set opacity by toggling a class via JS. Something like:
`$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(){$(this).find('.item.active .carousel-caption > div').css({opacity: 1})});` Sample code is not tested, but you should get the idea

Comment: Thanks aperture! I came to the same conclusion myself when i discovered another post referencing the fact that .bs.carousel was required. Thanks again.